# I have a 20Kg frame, What sort of motor will i need to rip it?

Tags: electric-vehicle

With the driver the total weight is roughly 80kg. Im trying to build a drift tricicle and was wondering what sort of motor i should be looking at. I Plan on having a 2:1 ration to double my torque. But have no clue what wattage motor i require to get what i want. Top speed inst important to me. Just wanna have some fun on it. 
Thanks guys

Comment: Search on the `Engineering Stack and possibly Electrical Engineering as this type of question has been asked before - usually as a project...

Comment: You want to rip your frame ? That can not be good for it and your safety. It will be much safer if has no rips.